# Stop recalculation of formula when preceeding cell doesn't actually change value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the following example:

```
Cell A1 with value 1
Cell A2 with formula =IF(A1>50,1,0)
Cell A3 with whatever calculation depending on A2 =foo(A2)
```

When I change the value in A1 to 100, then the value on A2 will change and that will make A3 recalculate. Perfect. But, when I change the value in A1 to 2, then A2 recalculates giving the same result, but A3 still will recalculate.

Is there a way to make excel not recalculate formulas when their preceeding cells don't really change value? My problem comes when foo is a very long, time consuming function and A1 changes constantly, but not always resulting on a change in A2.

To reproduce the issue `foo` may be like the following non-volatile UDF. It takes about 5 seconds to calculate on my PC.

```
 Function foo(x)
    foo = 0
    For j = 1 To 100
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        foo = foo + 0.01
    Next i
    Next j
    
End Function
```

Comment: is `foo` a volatile function?

Comment: @ScottCraner No. Changing any other cell won't make foo recalculate.

Comment: I can't reproduce, can you show foo so we can test?

Comment: @ScottCraner Please see my edit.

Comment: From my understanding, if any of the arguments in a UDF are changed, the UDF will recalculate.  Since A2 is being recalculated, I think it's technically considered 'changed' even though the calculation results in the same value.  So I think it's working by design and can't be avoided (but more than happy to be proven wrong).

Comment: @sous2817 Not only UDF. Same behavior with everyday excel functions.